# Is there a Flex event fired after an object is displayed on the screen

Tags: apache-flex, image, events, flex3

I have an Image being loaded dynamically and being added to my larger application.

After the image is loaded, I then want to grab a bitmap of the display for printing purposes.

The issue is that I can't find any events that are guaranteed to be triggered *after* the image is rendered on the screen.

FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE sounds closest on paper but doesn't appear to do the trick.

To test, I'm adding a breakpoint to the end of a handler triggered by the event, and seeing whether the image is on screen when the breakpoint is triggered.

I'm being forced to use flex 3.3.

Answer (score 2):

Images are a special case--the component can be complete and visible in the display list before the image data itself is loaded and rendered.

For `s:Image`, take a look at the [`Image.ready`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Image.html#event%3aready) event.

If you're using `mx:Image`, look at [`Image.complete`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/SWFLoader.html#event%3acomplete) instead.  (There's also an `s:Image.complete`--see the flexdoc comments for how it differs from `ready`.)

Comment: A quick scout of the docs shows that that event isn't available for flex 3.3 which I'm being forced to use. I've updated the question now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `FlexEvent.SHOW` event?

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#event:show

Edit:

If you can find an event that gets fired after the data is loaded (Event.COMPLETE or FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE or something else), you might be able to get away with doing a callLater() and assuming that the image will be rendered by the next frame.  Sort of a hack, but it might be worth a try.

Comment: FlexEvent.SHOW isn't called at any point, I believe that's only for when an object is explicitly made visible from invisible, whereas with a normal image load, it goes from undefined straight to visible.

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried that (I also tried 5 nested callLater()s which worked a small amount of the time).

Answer (score 0):

MX Image has a complete event, that I think is what you are looking for. FYI, each Class has a section in its language reference page called "Events."  It is frequently instructive to go through these and try ones that look likely. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Image.html#eventSummary

Comment: I've tried catching that event and it seems to be fired when the image finishes loading (As one would expect), *not* when the image has necessarily reached the screen.

Comment: You should be able to capture the pixels of the image at that point, unless you're trying to capture more than just the image. However, if add an event listener for updateComplete in reg'lar complete, you should find that everything is done at that point.